# JQuery data tables edit button link not using current index

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I've made a datatable and was able to add the edit and delete links to each row of the table. The links however do not seem to do anything. I am trying to redirect to an edit page upon click, but I am having trouble obtaining thethe id of the record that is in my model of the row that I'm wanting to edit to add to the url. Here is my markup/script that makes the table within a modal.

```
@model ReconciliationApp.Models.IReconciliationForm

<div class="img-responsive center-block" id="formButtons">
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group row col-sm-12">
            @Html.ActionLink("Top", "Top", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            @try
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Previous", null, new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Next", "Next", null, new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Bottom", "Bottom", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Previous", "Previous", null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Next", "Next", null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Bottom", "Bottom", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            }
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".browse-modal-lg">Browse</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade browse-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Browse Members</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left: 50px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
                            <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Products</h3>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md refresh-button" id="refresh-button">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span> Refresh
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%"></table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        var controller = "@ViewData["controller"]";
                        var productListVM = {
                            dt: null,

                            init: function () {
                                dt = $('#data-table').DataTable({
                                    "serverSide": true,
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "ajax": "/" + controller + "/DataTableGet",
                                    "columns": [
                                        { "title": "MemberID", "data": "MemberID", "searchable": false },
                                        { "title": "BrandID", "data": "BrandID" },
                                        { "title": "FirstName", "data": "FirstName" },
                                        { "title": "LastName", "data": "LastName" },
                                        { "title": "WhenCreated", "data": "WhenCreated" },
                                        { "title": "ProcessedBy", "data": "ProcessedBy" },
                                        {
                                            data: null,
                                            className: "center",
                                            defaultContent: `<a href="/${controller}/Edit/${(row[0].rowIndex)}" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="/${controller}/Delete/" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>`
                                        },
                                    ],

                                    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50], [5, 10, 25, 50]],
                                });
                            },

                            refresh: function () {
                                dt.ajax.reload();
                            }
                        }
                        // Edit record
                        $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            editor
                                .title('Edit record')
                                .buttons({ "label": "Update", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } })
                                .edit($(this).closest('tr'));
                        });

                        // Delete a record
                        $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            editor
                                .title('Edit record')
                                .message("Are you sure you wish to delete this row?")
                                .buttons({ "label": "Delete", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } })
                                .remove($(this).closest('tr'));
                        });

                        $('#refresh-button').on("click", productListVM.refresh);

                        productListVM.init();
                    })
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in

```
`defaultContent: `<a href="/${controller}/Edit/${(row[0].rowIndex)}" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="/${controller}/Delete/" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>``
```

I'm successfully able to add the controller (dynamically) into the url to direct to, but the url needs a particular record, or id to edit/delete, but I can't seem to find a way to be able to get the current row that the link is on. Is this possible at all? With a bunch of research here are some of the things I've tried so far, but to no avail.

1. I've made the rowIndex variable and passed it into the url similar to the controller
   `var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;`
2. I've made the table variable and then passed the second part as the last parameter in the url.
   `var table = $('#table-data').DataTable(); ${table.row(this).index()}`
3. The above are workarounds, but I would prefer to get the Id (which is part of my model) of the row that the link is on. I've tried referencing the model directly like Model.Id, but that doesn't seem to be working at all.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, as I'm somewhat new to javascript/jquery. Thanks!

Comment: try  table.row(this).data() to get data of the clicked row.While adding add a sr no  every row and try to access this sr no column

Comment: hmmm, the table simply will not render when I put that it, same happens when my other attempt. I hardcoded a value to check to make sure the link would work and it does so I know my end goal is correct, I just don't know why the table wouldn't render when passing it data.

Answer (score 0):

Basically after looking at the datatables documentation for the umpteenth time I ended up taking out the default content and replaced it with render and called a function which returned the data I needed. Then passed it as a variable into the url. Here is my changed script.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {

                    var controller = "@ViewData["controller"]";
                    var productListVM = {
                        dt: null,

                        init: function (oObj) {
                            dt = $('#data-table').DataTable({
                                "serverSide": true,
                                "processing": true,
                                "ajax": "/" + controller + "/DataTableGet",
                                "columns": [
                                    { "title": "MemberID", "data": "MemberID", "searchable": false },
                                    { "title": "BrandID", "data": "BrandID" },
                                    { "title": "FirstName", "data": "FirstName" },
                                    { "title": "LastName", "data": "LastName" },
                                    { "title": "WhenCreated", "data": "WhenCreated" },
                                    { "title": "ProcessedBy", "data": "ProcessedBy" },

                                    {
                                        data: null,
                                        className: "center",
                                        //re: `<a href="/${controller}/Edit/${}" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="/${controller}/Delete/" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>`,
                                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {


                                            return '<a href="/' + controller + '/Edit/' + data.Id + '" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="/' + controller + '/Delete/' + data.Id + '">Delete</a>';
                                        }
                                    },
                                ],

                                "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50], [5, 10, 25, 50]],
                            });
                        },

                        refresh: function () {
                            dt.ajax.reload();
                        }
                    }
                    // Edit record
                    $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        editor
                            .title('Edit record')
                            .buttons({ "label": "Update", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } })
                            .edit($(this).closest('tr'));
                    });

                    // Delete a record
                    $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        editor
                            .title('Edit record')
                            .message("Are you sure you wish to delete this row?")
                            .buttons({ "label": "Delete", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } })
                            .remove($(this).closest('tr'));
                    });

                    $('#refresh-button').on("click", productListVM.refresh);

                    productListVM.init();
                })
            </script>
```